# Make a hyperlink unclickable with css

Tags: css, hyperlink

I was wondering is there could be a trick in Css3 how to make a hyperlink loose its function, simply put, to disable the on click function ( so that it appears like a normal hyperlink but has no function like a paragraph) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<a href="http://example.com" class="inactive">Link</a>

.inactive {
   pointer-events: none;
   cursor: default;
}
```

The `cursor:default` property is if you want the cursor to be just an arrow. If you want it to act like a link (with the "hand" cursor), then remove it.

Comment: Note that the link will still be clickable in IE < 11 as the `pointer-events` property isn’t supported there (see http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events)

Answer (score 2):

CSS only solution is not cross browser supported at current time. But it is possible using pointer-events: none;

```
a.disabled {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

And there is no need to set disabled link cursor to default, cause links with `pointer-events: none;` has default cursor already.

Answer (score 0):

By any chance if you want this for the parent link of a dropdown menu, like:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-parent">Products</a>

  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Product 1</a>
    <a href="#">Product 2</a>
    <a href="#">Product 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

May be you don't want to see **#** upon hovering the content, neither **javascript:void(0)**.

Then just simply remove the **href** attribute in the parent link:

```
  <a class="dropdown-parent">Products</a>
```

This is valid. ( ref: [w3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#attr-hyperlink-href) )

No need to use any css or js code for that.

For more detail, you can visit [this](https://css-tricks.com/how-to-disable-links/) page.